# where can i find Conditional Css for ie

Tags: html, css

```
I am trying to understand that what kind of CSS inside the html class="ie.".
```

Is there any CSS file for these statements, if they are then what are the CSS
 elements being used in these style sheets.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: They’re just class names to indicate the browser version. They don’t have to be used in any way. They can be via CSS selectors or JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at are [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).  They are a Microsoft standard they baked into older versions of IE since the rendering "quirks" could vary so much from version to version.  Any non Internet Explorer browser will render those as comments and go about their merry way.  However, older versions of IE will so those comments and render them as content if the version matches.  For instance, IE6 would see your markup and render like this:

```
<html class="ie6">
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
```

What this allows you to do now is write CSS that targets Internet Explorer 6 *specifically* -- any selector that is prefixed with `.ie6` will only be applied to the IE6 browser.  Sad that it is necessary, but useful to have.

Please note that in IE10 MS felt that there browsers were now sufficiently quirk-free and standards compliant to no longer necessitate supporting any conditional comments, so they won't work IE9+.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you feel this best answers the question, please select it as such. Otherwise, if you need clarification, I'd be glad to provide it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that conditional comments will not work within your stylesheets. Instead, you can use conditional comments inside your HTML.  First I would apply different CSS classes / ID's to elements so you can then target with CSS.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <div id="ie_wrapper" class="ie">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
    <div id="ie_wrapper">
<![endif]-->
```